# Check if string contains substring in VHS 2.4

Tags: string, typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

How can I check if a string contains a specific substring?
E.g. I have an array of objects called `{category.files}` and output each object name.

```
<f:for each="{category.files}" as="file">
    <p>{file.name}</p>
</f:for>
```

Now I try to check if the name contains a specific substring and if true output it? In my case I search for the substring **fire**.

I found the VHS Method [contains](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/1.9.1/If/String/ContainsViewHelper.html) but I don't know how to use it, since there is no real example included.

How does it work in my case?

```
<f:for each="{category.files}" as="file">
                                  ???            ???                 ??
    <v:if.string.contains then="[mixed]" else="[mixed]" haystack="{file}" needle="fire">
       <!--output it if found -->

       <!-- else, do nothing -->
    </v:if.string.contains>
</f:for>
```

So in other words, I try to search **fire** in the **haystack**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
heystack = string to compare
needle   = string to find
```

if `{file.name}` can have the needle you should do something like this:

```
  <f:for each="{category.files}" as="file">
    <v:condition.string.contains haystack="{file.name}" needle="fire">
      <f:then>
        Needle found
      </f:then>
      <f:else>
        Needle not found
      </f:else>
    </v:condition.string.contains>
  </f:for>
```

**Edited**: As mentioned in the comments the asked ViewHelper `v:if.string.contains`was renamed to `v:condition.string.contains` in the version which was used.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I can't test it right now, because I get `Could not analyse class:FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers\If\String\ContainsViewHelper maybe not loaded or no autoloader?`. I tried to use the vhs code in a partial of an extension. Maybe I have to include VHS first?

Comment: Try to add ```{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}``` at the beginning of your template

Comment: Hmm, I tried it but still the same error message. Do I have to include VHS in `ext_localconf.php` or somewhere so the extension can use it?

Comment: @EdwardBlack what version of `vhs` you're using? There are no more `v:if`ViewHelpers, only `v:condition`: [v:condition.string.contains](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Condition/String/ContainsViewHelper.html)

Comment: Hmm, I am using v2.4.0

Comment: It works with `v:condition` :) if you change your solution accordingly then I accept your answer :)